# Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\iedan\modelo\UsuarioDao.php on line 37

Tags: php, login

tengo este error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\iedan\modelo\UsuarioDao.php on line 37

aquí esta el código

```
<?php 

include 'Conexion.php';
include '../entidades/Usuario.php';


class UsuarioDao extends Conexion
{
   protected static $cnx;

private static function getConexion()
{
    self::$cnx = Conexion::conectar();
}

private static function desconectar()
{
    self::$cnx = null;
}

/** 
* metodo para validar el login
*
* @param object $usuario
* @return boolean
*/
public static function login($usuario)
{

    $query = "SELECT id, nombre, usuario, rol, fecha_registro FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password";

    self::getConexion();

    $resultado = self::$cnx->prepare($query);

    $resultado->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario->getUsuario());
    $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password->getPassword()); //esta linea es la del error

    $resultado->execute();

    if($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
        return "ok";
    }

    return "falso";

  }
}
```

me dice que la variable no esta definida, pero todas estan definidas aqui:

```
<?php 

/**
* 
*/
class Usuario
{

private $id;
private $nombre;
private $usuario;
private $password;
private $rol;
private $fecha_registro;

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getNombre(){
    return $this->nombre;
}

public function setNombre($nombre){
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
}

 public function getUsuario(){
    return $this->usuario;
}

public function setUsuario($usuario){
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
}

public function getPassword(){
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password){
    $this->password = $password;
}

public function getRol(){
    return $this->rol;
}

public function setRol($rol){
    $this->rol = $rol;
}

public function getFecha_registro(){
    return $this->fecha_registro;
}

public function setFecha_registro($fecha_registro){
    $this->fecha_registro = $fecha_registro;
}
}
```

si alguien me puede indicar a que se debe,
de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es tu argumento **$usuario**, estás utilizando **$password**.

`$usuario->getPassword()` en vez de `$password->getPassword()`.

Comment: perdona, pero veo que si esta usando $password->getPassword();

Comment: Exacto, por eso le comento qué utilize $usuario (el argumento qué recibe) en vez de $password

Comment: ah genial si ya entendí tu respuesta :D

Comment: hey amigo era eso,  sigo aprendiendo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me sucedió, porque al escribir el valor de un dato, que era: lugar de nacimiento,escribí la letra b equivocadamente, en vez de colocar el lugar de nacimiento, que era el dato que debía agregar y lo resolví yendo a la base de datos de mi sistema, y borre la b y coloque Caracas y me apareció la interface de mi sistema todo bien.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/401949)